# Convert existing project into Android project in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

How do you convert an existing project into an Android project in Eclipse?

In particular, I want to convert a plain old Java project into an Android Library project.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the command line project update: android update project --path [projectpath]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What subsystem/plugin are you using for Eclipse Android development?

Generally speaking, the process is called "changing the project nature"
e.g.,

http://enarion.net/programming/tools/eclipse/changing-general-project-to-java-project/

Comment: Thanks Uri. That seems to be the first step of a (or the only) way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! I created a new Android project and then copied parts of its .classpath and .project files over to my existing project.

Comment: This answer could be made a lot more helpful if someone could supply the appropriate nature entry for Android projects.

Answer (score 75):

You need to change the nature of the project (this has already been answered, but nobody gave the actual string you need for that.)

- Close eclipse
- Open the .project file in your project
- Make the natures section look like:

  ```
  <natures>
      <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
      <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
  </natures>
  ```

Start eclipse again, have fun.

Note: If you are using **maven** you can configure the project's nature in your pom, see the [maven eclipse plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/provide-project-natures-and-build-commands.html)

Comment: Works with just closing and reopening the project. No need to close Eclipse... at least it works in Indigo.

Comment: And it did (and will) continue to do so in future releases of Eclipse because this is precisely what closing and reopening the project does: reading the `.project`-file

Answer (score 22):

I had an app that was built with Eclipse 3.5 and used java projects instead of properly built Android Library projects.  I'm not sure how it originally worked (the app was published and worked fined), but I couldn't get it to run when I tried setting up a dev environment on a different machine.  I keep getting ClassNotFoundExceptions for references to the Java project.

Since I had a couple years of check-in history, I really didn't want to move projects as some answers stated.  For me, converting the Java project into a proper Android Library made more sense.

Here are the steps I had to take to get it working:

Add AndroidNature to ".project" file

```
<natures>
<nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Add a simple "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.convertproject.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
</manifest>
```

Add a "project.properties" file

```
target=android-7
android.library=true
```

- Create an empty folder off the root of the project for called: "res"
- Refresh in Eclipse
- Right click on project, select Android Tools, Fix Project Properties
  Rebuild

**NOTE:** when you add library to your main project, import using the Android / Libray tab (under project properties) instead of Java Build Path / Projects

Comment: after doing your suggestions, I still have to delete the project and reimported again for eclipse considering it as android project

Comment: typing error "AndroidManifest.xml" missing letter 'i'

Comment: If you are using andmore eclipse plugin, you may add the nature `<nature>org.eclipse.andmore.AndroidNature</nature>` instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is correct and fully comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. Here are my steps:

- create an new android project
- copy .project, .classpath files into the plain old Java project
- refresh the plain old Java project in eclipse, and then the "Android Tools" appears at context menu when you right click the plain old Java project.
- "Android Tools" | "fix Project Properties"

In the last step,  Eclipse will add "Android Resource Manager", "Android Pre Compiler" and "Android Package Builder" into "Builders" and soon compile the project,  create the "gen" folder, BuildConfig.java and R.java.

done.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. Copy an AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties file to the root directory of this project.
2. Click "File" -> "Import", choose "Android" -> "Existing Android Code Into Workspace".
3. Configure proper source code path and Android Lib version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject)?

I don't know if there's a way to convert an existing Java project, but if not I'd suggest building a new library project as described and then moving your code to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of it, but it's more about converting an existing Android project into an Android Library project. Building a new project from scratch is not that hard, but I wanted to know if there was an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to convert I usually just create a new project and copy the files in there.

If I took the time to do it properly, it would've been a Mavenized project which I can just import.  You can look at my app to help you get some ideas.  https://github.com/trajano/GasPrices