# Convert java project into android project on Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have seen a question about converting android to java project. Now I want to know about Converting Java project into Android  Project. Is there any way? Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2959820/403455

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First Way**

1. Install [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
2. Right click on java project
3. Select Android > Convert to Android project.
4. Supply `/res` folder, `/AndroidManifest.xml` and `/default.properties` if needed.

**Second Way: UPD**

Actually, the "First Way" doesn't work with latest ADT plugin versions, for some reason google has removed the  convert command. Another way would be:

1. Check in your java project into a VCS (svn or git or whatever)
2. Delete it from workspace
3. Import the project from VCS
4. On import, select Create New Project -> Android

**Third Way**

Why not just copy sources to a newly created Android project :) ?

**Fourth Way: UDP** :)

1. Remove the java project from workspace
2. Start create new Android project wizard
3. Select create from existing source option and point to your java project folder.

Comment: The first way no longer works. The second way also does not seem to work anymore. The fourth way also does not seem to work. With the fourth way, you must have an android manifest there for it to work.

Comment: There is no longer an 'Android' context menu option for 'Project'.  There is only 'Android Tools', and NO 'Convert to Android project' option!

Comment: I have a java project and now I want to convert it to Android application. There are two native libraries being used in my java app aswell. so which solution I should opt for?

Comment: after doing all these steps restart eclipse worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

[Convert existing project into Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959820/convert-existing-project-into-android-project-in-eclipse)