# Converting Eclipse Java Project to Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

OK, first off, I HAVE read both [Convert java project into android project on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171327/convert-java-project-into-android-project-on-eclipse) and  [Convert java project into android project on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171327/convert-java-project-into-android-project-on-eclipse)
but my problem here is a little different, and none of those solutions listed work at all. This is with Eclipse Classic 3.7.2

Basically, I'm doing a bit of collaborative work on a project that comes from subversion. I've been tasked with creating an Android branch. So I grab the eclipse project from subversion, and then it should be easy to change this project to Android, right? Except it seems to be anything but. I have tried all that has been listed. There is no convert button. If I try to create a new Android project from existing source, it says 'Eclipse project already found!', if I delete the .project it demands a manifest file, I create another android project and just copy the manifest file over, no go. Everything compiles, but then I get a lot of errors in logcat. The first one being "Failed to load properties file for project". I copy over the properties file, and I still get the error. Same thing occurs if I modify the nature in .project .

I just want this to convert this to an android project, get rid of any compile time errors that might occur due to a mismatch of libraries between Java and Dalvik, then upload it as a branch. I could potentially create a new java project and copy over source, but then I'm not entirely sure how I can upload that to subversion as a branch, since I'm not modifying the stuff I got from the repository...

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: In response to one supplied answer to create a new android project, and use existing source, this simply doesn't work.  I point it to the directory of the Java non-android project, it tells me that a project already exists in that directory. I delete the .project file, then I get the error "Build path contains duplicate entry 'src' for project com_android_pdstore.

Comment: Create an Android project with a different name and copy the source in.

Comment: we don't really know what the errors are , so the best way as Che Jami said, create a new project and copy code into .

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new android project and choose 'create project from existing source', I had this type of problem once, and that was the solution.

Comment: I have edited the original post to describe what happens when I attempt this. Doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Right Clicking on the Project and then Android Tools ,click Fix Project Properties, could be an incompatible API build.