# convert java project to android phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova

i have seen a question about converting android to java project. Now I want to know about Converting Java project into Android Phonegap. Project. Is there any way? i read from this [Convert java project into android project on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171327/convert-java-project-into-android-project-on-eclipse), but for the fourth way, create new android project and point to existing java source, but in the java don't have the AndroidManifest.xml. How we want to create new? Thanks

Comment: Java project and Phonegap are completely different, AFAIK. One is purely Java, the other is HTML page.

Comment: phonegap uses HTML5 and javascript for coding and is not a java project. So, conversion is not possible

Comment: ya i know that, If java to android?but in phonegap there allowed to used java, so i do not know how, i have a web apps which we build by using jsp for the view and java for the domain, services and controller. now i'm moving to convert it to phonegap. How can i do it? for the jsp i change to html and it also works but what i stuck is where should i put all my java code. is it in the sama package with the one that we call index.html in android phonegap? then how should i make it works. Should i make it as plugin? or any other solution? Thanks.