# Android Intent-filter VerifyError

Tags: java, android, intentfilter, verifyerror

I have a rather unusual issue.  My program works fine when opened directly.  When opened via an intent-filter custom extension match it crashes with a VerifyError.  The class it can't find is in library jar in a java project dependency.

Bear in mind this works perfectly when opened from the app drawer.

As a quick check I copied the jar from the java project dependency into my Android project.  Afterwards it runs fine even from an intent-filter extension match.

Does anyone know why the class lookup would behave differently based on the intent-filter match?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try converting the java project to an android library and it was relatively simple.  After conversion I no longer needed to copy the sub-library to the main Android project, it worked right from the Android library.  I'm not sure why the java library *almost worked*, but I suppose it's best to simply convert everything to Android if possible.

Here's a link for conversion:

[Convert existing project into Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959820/convert-existing-project-into-android-project-in-eclipse)