# Linking a project as a library to other projects

Tags: java, android, collaboration

I am new to Java and have been learn as I go.

I am having a problem where I have developed a library of objects in one project and I now want to use them in two other projects. I started doing this by copying the packages from the first project into the second and third projects, however I would now like to make changes to the library and I would like these to be reflected in the second and third project, which obviously they are not.

Project1
   -package1
   -package2
   -package3

Project2
   -packageA
   -packageB
   -package1
   -package2
   -package3

Project3
   -packageC
   -packageD
   -package1
   -package2
   -package3

I would like for the packages to be in the second and third project to be updated automatically when I update them in the first project, although I also don't mind doing the refresh manually. At the moment it is just me working on all off the projects but it could be the case in the future where more people are working on them, therefore I don't mind suggestion which would have this move onto some collaborative platform (I'm aware of SVN but have never set one up)

Comment: just import them as modules

Comment: which IDE are you using ?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you can do this as follows.

1. Import your project to your workspace.

**Mark it as library project**

Right click your project you want to make as library and select Properties. Select Android on the left and tick the checkbox IsLibrary. Done.

**Reference the marked project**

Right click your project in which you want to add the library project and select Properties. Select Android on the left and Add... your marked project. It will be added to the list and is ready to use. Now you are able to access all classes and ressources (e.g. drawables, strings) from the referenced, marked project. Awesome, eh? :)

Comment: Thank you, but the project that I wish to make a library is not an Android project, it's a regular Java project (although one of the other project I wish to use it in is an Android project, the third is a NetBeans).

It the properties of the project I only have
;Resourses
-Builders
-Java Build Path
-Java Code Style
-Java Compiler
-Java Editor
-Javadoc Location
-Project References
-Refactoring History
-Task Tags
-Validation
-WikiText

Comment: I converted my java project to an Android Application Project using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959820/convert-existing-project-into-android-project-in-eclipse